# Deploying embedded tomcat enabled spring-boot app using IntelliJ

Tags: maven, tomcat, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have a spring-boot based application, using embedded tomcat. I have no problem when deploying via `mvn spring-boot:run` goal, **but** I have a problems when I try to deploy using intelliJ spring-boot plugins. Important note, we have modified the default pom, turning our app into a war that could be deployed into a full tomcat[Traditional Deployment](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#howto-traditional-deployment), but this in development mode will be better to just deploy the app using the embedded tomcat. The problem is that basically we ended with this message when trying to run the spring boot app from intelliJ

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:163) ~[spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.retrieveBeanMethodMetadata(ConfigurationClassParser.java:380) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:314) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:198) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:167) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:152) ~[spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

Do you have any ideas of why is this happening ? and how can we solve it ?

**EDIT:**

I am using IntelliJ IDEA **2017.2** (just in case the build is idea-IU-172.3317.76), and as  a SSCCE, lets use the [getting-started example of spring-boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/), and lets apply the changes proposed for Traditional Deployment (the first link) we will have the following files

**pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Then we will have the **Application.java**

```java
package hello;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

        String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        Arrays.sort(beanNames);
        for (String beanName : beanNames) {
            System.out.println(beanName);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

}
```

And I didn' modify the **HelloController.java** but just for completeness:

```java
package hello;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
    }

}
```

This example runs without problem using `mvn spring-boot:run` but doesn't run when using the spring-boot  intelliJ's plug-in

Comment: Are you using the Enterprise Edition sdk?

Comment: No, I am using J2SE, actually openjdk

Comment: javax.servlet is only available in J2EE I believe.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860022/wheres-javax-servlet

Comment: yes, but all those dependencies are (or should be) provided by tomcat, the problem here is that when I run the app intelliJ those dependencies are just not available, but when I run from console they are, and I don't know why xD

Comment: Maybe here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33591035/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-servlet-servletcontext

Comment: the accepted solution was gradle related, and the most voted answer rely again on plain maven task, and not the spring boot plugin from intelliJ, but if there is no other way, I guess I will just use the maven approach and drop the intelliJ plugin

Comment: Umm did you add `spring-boot-starter-web` to the list of your dependencies?

Comment: yes, it is my first dependency actually

Comment: Could you share a [sscce](http://sscce.org) to reproduce it? I think pom & simple main class should suffice. Also please let us know what IJ version you're using

Comment: Sorry, I was out of office and at home didn't have enough time to test this. I've updated my question with the sscce.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note** - this answer references Spring documentation for v 1.5.6.RELEASE (current release)

---

**Analyses:**

Running the main class from IJ is like executing your app from command line. As such, the classpath will include only `compile` and `runtime` scoped dependencies. [`Provided`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) means that it'll be needed during compilation, but you expect the JDK or the container to *provide* it for your app at runtime:

> `provided`
>   This is much like `compile`, but indicates **you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime**. For example, when building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to scope `provided` because the web container provides those classes. This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive.

On the other hand, the [`spring-boot-maven-plugin`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/exclude-dependency.html) uses a different classpath to execute the `run` goal:

> By default, both the `repackage` and the `run` goals will include **any `provided` dependencies** that are defined in the project. A boot-based project should consider `provided` dependencies as container dependencies that are required to run the application.

---

**Conclusion and solutions:**

So it's a classpath configuration issue. As you mentioned, for [war packaging](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging) or [traditional deployment](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-traditional-deployment), you should exclude the embedded servlet container. However, to be able to run the app during development, you want the embedded container.

As a solution or work around, you have at least the following 2 options:

**1)** Remove the `<scope>provided</scope>` from the `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` dependency declaration. If you wanted to, you could remove that dependency altogether, as [Tomcat is the default container used by `spring-boot-starter-web`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-boot-starter-web), but perhaps it's best to leave it and add a comment, so you won't forget about it when releasing

**2)** A neat trick that works with IJ and would make it easier to not forget to uncomment `provided` before production release, is to leave the dependency as it is now, and add a maven `dev` profile which you can activate from IJ. This way, by default it will be `provided` and it can be safely packaged into a war, and only when developing and manually activating the profile it will be included. After adding the profile, reimport  your maven project so you can select the profile:

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

[image: reimport project and activate profile]

Answer (score 0):

if you are using maven project then you need to add `javax.servlet-api` dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

you can also download jar from  http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5/servlet-api-2.5.jar

Comment: thank you @Mayank Sharma, but still having the same problem with this added to the pom.xml

Comment: delete `.m2` fillder and reupdate the project, and run it