# Spring Boot Embedded Tomcat IllegalStateException/"Error weaving class"

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

**Problem**

While working on a spring-boot project something (probably a dirty shutdown of my laptop) happened and I get Errors like the following:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. 
Could not load [org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/batch/internal/AbstractBatchImpl.class]. 
The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
...
```

```
2019-11-29 11:45:27.540  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.s.o.j.p.ClassFileTransformerAdapter:
 Error weaving class [net/sf/ehcache/transaction/xa/EhcacheXAException] 
with transformer of class [com.broadleafcommerce.enterprise.workflow.transform.SandBoxClassTransformer]

java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException: 
Unable to convert net.sf.ehcache.transaction.xa.EhcacheXAException to sandbox: 
Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. 
Could not load [javax/transaction/xa/XAException.class]. 
The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
...
```

This happens when I run the project from Intellij. When I run from console via `mvn spring-boot: run`, there are no issues, because they are different run contexts ([this question has some details about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45515849/deploying-embedded-tomcat-enabled-spring-boot-app-using-intellij)).

**Analysis**

I suspect that, given an unclean shutdown, the cache of tomcat or other deployment descriptors are corrupt.

I was looking for the (embedded) Tomcat work directory and did not find it (maybe there is none, it's all in RAM?).
Additionally, I did an Invalidate Caches/Restart in Intellij, purged the dependencies and then redownloaded them.

**Quick Fix**

What helped was deleting the `.idea` directory inside my project folder. But I do not know the reason for this "corruption" nor how to specifically fix it.

**Problem reappears in another context**

After fixing the IntelliJ setup (by deleting .idea, reimporting the project, setting run configs) this same thing happened in a Docker container with a fresh build. So it might not have been an issue with Intellij but the spring-boot startup.

**Question**

Does anyone know how to clean the state of embedded Tomcat or where the reasons for these errors lie?

Comment: Did you try File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart in IDEA?

Comment: Yes, will update, did not work. That was my first try.

Comment: It also appears inside the docker container, which might mean it was only partially related or caused by intellij.

Comment: Your remark about it failing in the same way in docker seems to suggest that this isn't an intellij thing at all. If that's the case you should remove all reference to intellij from the question and you'll widen the audience of people who might be able to help.